# Helm hook not triggered post upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have been trying to use [helm hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) example from this page. I had just changed the command to `touch /tmp/flag`  from the first example. But that doesn't seem to get executed, I couldn't find any flag file in the /tmp. Is there any way I can attach stdout of the hook command and visualit output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helm hooks runs in their own containers.

So your file `/tmp/flag` is touched inside hook container, which is then discarded upon completion.

Use PVC to share filesystem between hook POD and your application POD